# Seeing a Java program's native assembly code -- What's the easiest way in Windows?

Tags: java, jvm

I've tried following the advice found @ https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly and http://alexshabanov.com/2011/12/29/print-assembly-for-java/ , but it wasn't of much help. I'm running a 64bit JVM on Windows7, and I've put the suggested `hsdis-i386.dll` file in all folders there's a jvm.dll, just to be sure.

I seem to have several JVM installations (at least I have one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` and other in `C:\Program Files\Java`), so I don't know whether this is making any difference. From what I've seen, doing a java -d32 yields an error, so I must be using the 64bits version one only.

When trying to run

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -server -cp . HelloWorldApp
```

only my

> Hello World!

message is shown, so nothing seems to be happening. Maybe the problem is that hsdis-i386.dll should have other name?

Btw, I'd like to stay away from having to build any kind of source files myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hotspot won't begin compiling and optimizing until it knows what is important, and when you run such a short program it doesn't have the opportunity to kick in. Give it something more substantial.

Comment: Hmm. I'd just like to see what's the native code of my application. Doesn't it turn to native code *every* bit of code? Or it will by default interpret the code and just compile to native some critical parts?

Comment: You seem to be right. Put it on a loop and then got some error stating it isn't finding hsdis-amd64.dll.

Comment: Yes, I used my 32 bit installation with the given .dll and it worked wonders. I think I'd have to compile myself the .dll code if I wanted it to run with my 64bit JVM, though.